# Intercepting Keyboard Data on a Micro Controller

Tags: usb, keyboard

Recently I have purchased male and female USB-C breakout boards. I intend to connect the male breakout to a keyboard and the female end to my computer using a USB-C cable and wire the breakouts together using a breadboard. I was wondering if it is possible to read the keystrokes being sent across the D- and D+ lines with a micro-controller.

Here is an image of how I currently have the breakout boards setup

[image]

Comment: Just a suggestion, you should probably edit your question and replace Micro Controller with Arduino so as not to be off topic.

Comment: Welcome to SE/Arduino! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". -- Would you mind to [edit] your question and extend on the reason, please? -- It is much simpler to capture key presses in the receiving operating system, or in the keyboard before being transmitted. USB is quite complex "on the wire," however, you might try what small logic analyzers are doing. These commonly have special hardware involved, a simple device like the microcontroller of an Arduino cannot do it.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdgULBpRoXk). The author decodes the USB HID protocol by hand, with pen and paper.

Answer (score 1):

It would be far far easier to [interface an Arduino to an old PS2 keyboard](https://github.com/techpaul/PS2KeyAdvanced).

USB is complex.  You would have to understand [USB protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_communications#Protocol_layer), then understand the [HID (Human Interface Device) protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class) inside of the USB protocol.  As HID can interface a number of devices like mice and keyboards, you might have to then understand the keyboard portion of the HID protocol.

As a point of reference, commercial USB analyzers cost hundreds of dollars.  [This USB analyzer cost about $500](https://www.adafruit.com/product/708).

As an alternative, have you considered an all software USB monitor? These normally reside on the same computer as the USB Device is attached to. [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) should be able to do this.

Also, assuming that is a [Pro Micro](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12640) used on the keyboard, consider adding code to its Atmel processor to send out keyboard activity on an unused pin. This approach might proved much easier then monitoring the keyboard after its data has been incorporated into the USB protocol.

Comment: I don't want to discourage you.  I just what to point out the difficulties of creating a USB interface.  Especially one that is not a USB Device or USB Host (i.e. one that can monitor but will not enumerate or try to take control of the USB).

Comment: [This is a really old thread that discusses a USB Sniffer](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/decoding-the-nzri-data-usb-sniffer/55302). Even back then (likely only USB 3.0 existed at the time) it was thought to be a really difficult task.

Comment: OP doesn't want a general USB sniffer. only keyboard

Comment: Btw you can use Wireshark to catch USB communication directly on the system. His question looks more like XY problem. If he has everything on the photo, he could just program it directly into that on-keyboard MCU (looks like Pro Micro with usb-c?)

Comment: @Juraj, I think once you start using USB to communicate you are going to have to buy into the entire USB protocol.  But please follow up w/links to project that monitor only a USB/HID/Keyboard.  I would be fun to figure out how they did it!

Comment: Good points @KIIV.  I forgot about Wireshark.  And you are correct, That Pro Micro should be able to monitor and spit out the keyboard activity way easier than picking apart the USB signal.

Comment: so my though is that there are Arduino projects with keyboard as input and there are projects where the Arduino is the keyboard. so it should be enough to copy keys from input to output. but of course with the keyboard on the photo the keyboard is already an Arduino.

Comment: I see, I was hoping for a simple way to have a microcontroller (like another Pro-Micro for example) to read in key inputs sent over USB. Creating a USB interface seems like it is currently out of my scope.

Comment: You can try @Juraj 's idea.  But you can't have 2 keyboards.  Well, you might be able to ... but you don't want 2 keyboards.  You want 1 keyboard and something that will listen.  So you need to keep the new keyboard from getting enumerated by the USB host.  But you still need it to listen.  This is where I'm in unknown waters.  It's almost like you need the listener to act like the 1st keyboard except it can not talk back.  This isn't just out of your scope, it's out of most of our scopes!

Comment: Micro can't be an USB host. USB host shield would have to be used to read an USB keyboard. but again. here the keyboard is already an Arduino.